# how to make program in c#.net and use winpcap library in it?

Tags: .net, network-programming, packet-sniffers

I want to make project using winpcap library in c# .net. There is one library file in java named jpcap.jar. Which are the requirements to to make this project?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the .NET wrapper [Pcap.Net over at codeplex](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).

> Pcap.Net Features
>
> Including:
>
> - Getting the list of Live Devices on the local host.
> - Reading packets from Live Devices (Network Devices) and Offline Devices
>   (Files) using the different WinPcap
>   methods.
> - Receiving statistics on the entire capture.
> - Receiving statistics of packets instead of the full packets.
> - Using different sampling methods.
> - Applying Berkley Packet Filters.
> - Sending packets to Live Devices directly or using WinPcap's send
>   queues.
> - Dumping packets to Pcap files.
> - Using Enumerables to receive packets (and LINQ).

Comment: Do you have any idea of packet blocking using pcap library? or is there any other way to block specific packets.